# Choosing a specific region to live on Mars, how important will the degree of dust there be, compared with the availability of water?

Tags: mars, water, dust, environment, ice

[image: Watermap Mars1]
Credits: NASA/JPL-Caltech/ASU

The map above shows underground water ice on Mars, it's from the article [NASA's Treasure Map for Water Ice on Mars](https://nasa.gov/feature/jpl/nasas-treasure-map-for-water-ice-on-mars).
The blue and purple represent water ice less than 30 centimeters (one foot) below the surface, and the black zones indicate areas where a landing spacecraft would sink into fine dust.

> ..; the outlined box **(on the map)** represents the ideal region to send astronauts for them to dig up water ice.

**(emphasis added by me)**

But (part of) the albedo map of Mars below from [MARS Global Data Sets](https://mars.asu.edu/data/tes_albedo/) shows that this so-called "ideal region" is rather bright in general.

[image: Albedo map Mars]

From [Mars Global Surveyor Thermal Emission Spectrometer experiment: Investigation description and surface science results](https://mars.asu.edu/christensen/docs/christensen_tesreview_2001.pdf) (page 23,848):

> Therefore it is likely that the surface rocks and sands in the dark regions are less coated by bright dust than those seen at any site visited to date. It has been suggested that Mars dark regions are likely areas of active removal of bright dust by sand saltation or other means [*Thomas* 1984; *Christensen* 1988]. Landing sites in dark regions might provide an opportunity to directly sample exposed, dust-free rocks [*Edgett et all*., 1994].

So it might be that the "ideal region" in the outlined box will be rather dusty, despite not enough "to sink a spacecraft". And [Martian dust is poisonous, containing perchlorate](https://researchgate.net/publication/242525435_Perchlorate_on_Mars_A_chemical_hazard_and_a_resource_for_humans), so digging for the water ice would be better done without dust.

So to what extent will the presence of dust in a region with water ice close to the surface, be a reason to look elsewhere for better conditions ?

For example, there are two regions next to each other, one rather dusty with water ice 20 cm below the surface and the other almost free of dust but with water ice 30 cm below its surface.
What will be the choice, and with what reasons ?

Edit:

By comparing the [NASA  treasure map](https://nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia23514.jpg) with the [albedo map of Mars](https://mars.asu.edu/data/tes_albedo/) precisely, a few regions can be found that have **both** a low albedo **and** a water ice depth of 0.1 to 0.2 m.
Part of such a region is shown below at about 38.6⁰ N, 203.1⁰ East.

[image: Region with low albedo and subsurface ice]

The image above is part of [ESP_050156_2190](https://uahirise.org/ESP_050156_2190), click twice on it for a closer view.
Credit: NASA/JPL/University of Arizona

Comment: Is dust anywhere on Mars sink-into-able?

Comment: Yes and no.  Drop something some of the large dunes, leave for 100 years and it might well "sink". But not within a mission timeframe.  Certainly not in a "where did I put my spaceship" sense.

Comment: Martian dust is not notably poisonous, and spacecraft aren't going to sink into it.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff  https://hub.jhu.edu/magazine/2018/winter/mars-dust-medusae-fossae-formation/

Comment: @Cornelisinspace What of it? That article only mentions effects on instruments and solar power. It makes no claims of toxicity or other hazards to spacecraft.

Comment: Isn't chlorine poisonous to you ?

Comment: Elemental chlorine's fairly hazardous, but there isn't any on Mars. **Everything** is poisonous. Even helium has harmful effects on the nervous system under high enough pressures. We casually handle materials on Earth that are far more hazardous than Mars dust. Wash your hands recently? Pure perchlorate salts are about as toxic as soap, and the dust at the Phoenix site only had 0.5-1% perchlorate content. You were just scrubbing yourself with something about a hundred times as toxic as Mars dust.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff  Yes, there's no elemental chlorine, but it was detected by instruments as part of the perchlorate. I've added a link in my question that says perchlorates are hazardous. But they could be a resource too !

Comment: On one hand, the water on the Moon can be used for producing rocket fuel (not only as water itself). But on the other hand, the dust there can be everywhere and it even harms people.

Comment: Blue and low albedo at 38.3 N., 173.3 East.

Comment: Purple at 35 N., 171 - 172 East.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Water is extremely useful on Mars.  You can use it to generate oxygen directly via electrolysis and the hydrogen byproduct can be reacted with carbon dioxide to make even more water. We drink water. If they want to come home, water+carbon dioxide+power can produce methane and oxygen. That's the most likely rocket fuel to get home.

On the other hand, dust is everywhere.  You can't avoid it - the place has planet wide dust storms.  More dust, less dust, you have to deal with the dust either way.

But water you're going to need by lots.  Hundreds of cubic meters.  Stick with the water.

Edit to add:. Dust will interfere with almost all missions to Mars. Not having enough water will end missions.

Edit to add: To answer the 20cm Vs 30cm question.  Consider gardening on Earth.   How much harder is it too dig a 30cm hole, Vs 20cm?   Not all that hard.   In any near surface ice bed the local variation in depth will be more than 10cm.  The real question will be "Where is ice within 1m of the surface".

Once you've dug down to ice, as can put in a simple air lock, pump in CO2 and prevent the ice from subliming away.  If it's more than 1m down... Look at the problems Insight has had digging at all.

You must have water, dust is so much less important.  You can travel to features you're interested in.  You can't realistically dig water up from 70m down or carry tonnes for kilometers.

Comment: But would it not be important to have dust as little as possible ? Martian dust is poisonous !

Comment: Well, yes and no.  Most of it is iron oxides and titanomagnetite.  Not great, wouldn't want to eat, but not Poisonous.  I think you're thinking about perchlorates, which are a problem with the soil.  But this is a soluble problem - literally - they're very soluble in water.  Wash soil with water, distill the water, rinse and repeat.  Puns intended.  Or heat it to 500 degrees or so, perchlorates decompose into salts and oxygen.   Unless you're thinking something else?

Comment: Very nice answer! Since no good deed goes unpunished, I've just asked [Will MOXIE get clogged or chemically degraded by martian dust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46151/12102)

Comment: @uhoh  Not a very nice answer to me, I think its obvious that there are places on Mars with much less dust on the ground, and that will make it easier to handle, especially when you need to dig through that soil for water ice   I asked about the **choice** between  the **degree** of dust and the **degree** of availability of water ice.

Comment: @Cornelisinspace okay while I like the point raised in the answer, it technically isn't a "very nice answer" if it doesn't address your question.

Comment: @user2702772 They're also barely more toxic than table salt. The LD50 of sodium perchlorate is 2.1g/kg (compare to table salt at 3 g/kg), you'd have to sit down and eat a bowl of pure perchlorate salts. They substitute for iodine and cause thyroid issues at lower concentrations, but iodine supplements can compensate for that.

Comment: As another point of comparison, the sodium hypochlorite people are currently spraying all over the place has a LD50 of 192 mg/kg...almost 11 times as toxic as sodium perchlorate. We pour it in swimming pools. Mars dust is a minor annoyance at worst, its biggest significance is probably its impact on solar power.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff https://researchgate.net/publication/242525435_Perchlorate_on_Mars_A_chemical_hazard_and_a_resource_for_humans

Comment: @Cornelisinspace That paper backs up what I said about the iodine issues, and covers some approaches to removing perchlorates. It doesn't invalidate anything I've said. Perchlorates are mildly toxic with effects that can be directly mitigated with iodine supplements, present in small concentrations, do not bio-accumulate, are unstable and easily decomposed by heat or chemical/biological action, and they are highly soluble and easily washed out of soil. They're a minor detail to living on Mars.

Comment: Particularly note what I said about bio-accumulation. What manages to get absorbed without reacting with something gets excreted in the urine, with a serum half-life in humans of 6-8 hours. As a reactive oxidizer, it will quickly find some reducing agent to react with in water recycling or agricultural systems, and likely won't survive to reach a human a second time. What you need to be worried about in closed systems like this are things like heavy metals or persistent organic pollutants that could just build up over time and concentrate at the top of the food chain...the humans.

Comment: That is a lovely paper.  Bookmarked for later use!